# AngularJS: Refresh expired JWT token on 401 response

Tags: angularjs, jwt, angular-promise, csrf-token

I'm facing issue on refreshing expired JWT token based on 401 (unauthorized) header response. What i want is when user get 401 (header) response, than a new (refresh) JWT should generated by calling specific service (api).

I'm sending XSRF-TOKEN & access_token (JWT) in header response and these are working fine. I even also can get refresh (expired) token by calling api manually. But can't get it worked with 401 (header) response.

I've a factory that take care of this promise and intercepts header requests. My (factory) code looks like this.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('httpRequestInterceptor', httpRequestInterceptor);

function httpRequestInterceptor($cookies, $rootScope, $q, $location, $injector) {

  var replays = [];
  var refreshTokenPromise;

  var factory = {
    request: request,
    responseError: responseError
  };

  return factory;

  //////////

  function requestTodoWhenDone() {
    var token = store.get('token');

    return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: ApiEndpoint.url,
      params: {
        grant_type: 'refresh',
        id_token: $cookies.get('access_token')
      }
    })
      .success(function(response) {
        // Set the refreshed token.
        $cookies.put('access_token', response.data.access_token);
      })
      .then(function(){

        // Attempt to retry the request if request config is passed.
        if( !angular.isUndefined(requestTodoWhenDone) && requestTodoWhenDone.length > 0 ) {

          // Set the new token for the authorization header.
          requestTodoWhenDone.headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('access_token')
          };

          // Run the request again.
          return $http(requestTodoWhenDone);
        }

      });
  }

  //////////

  // Add authorization token to headers
  function request(config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    if ($cookies.get('access_token')) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('access_token');
    }

    return config;
  }

  // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
  function responseError(response, requestTodoWhenDone) {
    if (response.status === 401 && $cookies.get('access_token')) {
      return checkAuthorization(response);
    }

    return $q.reject(response);

    /////////

    function checkAuthorization(res) {
      return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

        var replay = {
          success: function(){
            $injector.get('$http')(res.config).then(resolve, reject);
          },
          cancel: function(){
            reject(res);
          }
        };

        replays.push(replay);
        console.log(replays);

        if (!refreshTokenPromise) {
          refreshTokenPromise = $injector.get('requestTodoWhenDone') // REFRESH TOKEN HERE
            .refreshToken()
            .then(clearRefreshTokenPromise)
            .then(replayRequests)
            .catch(cancelRequestsAndRedirect);
        }
      });

      ////////////

      function clearRefreshTokenPromise(auth) {
        refreshTokenPromise = null;
        return auth;
      }

      function replayRequests(auth) {
        replays.forEach(function(replay) {  
          replay.success();
        });

        replays.length = 0;

        return auth;
      }

      function cancelRequestsAndRedirect() {

        refreshTokenPromise = null;
        replays.forEach(function(replay) {  
          replay.cancel();
        });

        replays.length = 0;

        $cookies.remove('token');
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');

        // SET YOUR LOGIN PAGE
        $location.path('/login');
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Based on above code I'm getting following error in console when token expires (401 response).

**Console Error**

```
Error: "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: requestTodoWhenDoneProvider <- requestTodoWhenDone
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciable.
Thanks.

Comment: You have not defined a provider with that name according to your code. (`angular.module('myApp').provider('requestTodoWhenDoneProvider', requestTodoWhenDoneProvider);`)

Comment: I don't understand, could you please describe it more? Cause its not working. I've added it like;

`angular.module('yapApp').factory('httpRequestInterceptor', httpRequestInterceptor).provider('requestTodoWhenDone', requestTodoWhenDone);`

and than function for this outside of **httpRequestInterceptor** function;

`function requestTodoWhenDone() {}`

Comment: You are trying to `$inject` a provider that you have not defined: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: still stuck, any help would be highly appreciable or is there any other way around for refreshing token?

Dev Note: I've used following gist for refresh token.
https://gist.github.com/ygotthilf/3cf3e36bfbe9881f0e4b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i ended up with different way that solves the issue. But i still can't be able to redirect user to login page when my token inactive time is also expires (this happens after jwt expires).

Here is the code.

**authInterceptor.service.js**

```
angular.module('someApp').factory('AuthorizationTokenService', AuthorizationTokenService);

AuthorizationTokenService.$inject = ['$q', '$injector', '$cookies'];
function AuthorizationTokenService($q, $injector, $cookies) {
  // Local storage for token
  var tokenVM = {
    accessToken: null
  };

  // Subscribed listeners which will get notified when new Access Token is available
  var subscribers = [];

  // Promise for getting new Access Token from backend
  var deferedRefreshAccessToken = null;

  var service = {
    getLocalAccessToken: getLocalAccessToken,
    refreshAccessToken: refreshAccessToken,
    isAccessTokenExpired: isAccessTokenExpired,
    subscribe: subscribe
  };

  return service;

  ////////////////////////////////////

  // Get the new Access Token from backend
  function refreshAccessToken() {

    // If already waiting for the Promise, return it.
    if( deferedRefreshAccessToken ) {

      return deferedRefreshAccessToken.promise 

    } else {

      deferedRefreshAccessToken = $q.defer();

      // Get $http service with $injector to avoid circular dependency
      var http = $injector.get('$http');

      http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api_url',
        params: {
          grant_type: 'refresh',
          id_token: $cookies.get('access_token')
        }
      })
        .then(function mySucces(response) {
          var data = response.data;
          if( data ){
            // Save new Access Token
            $cookies.put('access_token', data.access_token);

            if( $cookies.get('access_token') ) {

              // Resolve Promise
              deferedRefreshAccessToken.resolve(data.access_token);

              // Notify all subscribers
              notifySubscribersNewAccessToken(data.access_token);
              deferedRefreshAccessToken = null;
            }
          }
        }, function myError(error) {
          deferedRefreshAccessToken.reject(error);
          deferedRefreshAccessToken = null;
        });

      return deferedRefreshAccessToken.promise;
    } 

  }

  function getLocalAccessToken() {
    // get accesstoken from storage - $cookies
    if ( $cookies.get('access_token') ) {
      var access_token = $cookies.get('access_token')
      return access_token;
    }
  }

  function isAccessTokenExpired() {
    // Check if expiresAt is older then current Date
  }

  function saveToken(accessToken) {
    // get accesstoken from storage - $cookies
    var access_token = $cookies.put('access_token');

    console.log('access_token ' + access_token);

    return access_token;
  }

  // This function will call all listeners (callbacks) and notify them that new access token is available
  // This is used to notify the web socket that new access token is available
  function notifySubscribersNewAccessToken(accessToken) {
    angular.forEach(subscribers, function(subscriber) {
      subscriber(accessToken);
    });
  }

  // Subscribe to this service. Be notifyed when access token is renewed
  function subscribe(callback) {
    subscribers.push(callback);
  }
}
```

Than in config (app.js) I've following code which intercepts appropriate header(s) and refresh (request) api on 401 response.

**Here is the config code**

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider'];
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  // Push httpRequestInterceptor
  // $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');

  //Intercept all http requests
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$injector', '$q', "AuthorizationTokenService", "$cookies", function ($injector, $q, AuthorizationTokenService, $cookies) {
    var cachedRequest = null;

    return {
      request: function (config) {
        //If request if for API attach Authorization header with Access Token
        if (config.url.indexOf("api") != -1) {
          // var accessToken = AuthorizationTokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
          console.log('cookie ' + $cookies.get('access_token'));
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('access_token');
        }
        return config;
      },
      responseError: function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
          // Detect if reponse error is 401 (Unauthorized)
          case 401:

          // Cache this request
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          if(!cachedRequest) {
            // Cache request for renewing Access Token and wait for Promise
            cachedRequest = AuthorizationTokenService.refreshAccessToken();
          }

          // When Promise is resolved, new Access Token is returend 
          cachedRequest.then(function(accessToken) {
            cachedRequest = null;
            if (accessToken) {
              // Resend this request when Access Token is renewed
              $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(resp) {
                // Resolve this request (successfully this time)
                deferred.resolve(resp);
              },function(resp) {
                deferred.reject();
                console.log('success: refresh token has expired');
              });
            } else {
              // If any error occurs reject the Promise
              console.log('error: refresh token has expired');
              deferred.reject();
            }
          }, function(response) {
            // If any error occurs reject the Promise
            cachedRequest = null;
            deferred.reject();
            return;
          });

          return deferred.promise;
        }

        // If any error occurs reject the Promise
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
  }]);
}
```

The code is working fine on 401 (response) case which happens when JWT expires. But its not redirecting me to login page (In this case I've added console in promise request in config instead of redirection code)

Please help on this, thanks...

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash, would you mind to guide on this matter?

Comment: After spending some more time I'm still not be able to redirect user to login page after when i got 401 response again (when validating token via interceptor). Please review my code above and guide me where I'm going wrong, i could really use some help here.